# При переносе сайта на nginx слетели все стили и роуты node.js

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, nginx, pm2

Всем привет! Помогите друзья. Я довольно зелёный парень, прошу помидорами не бросаться.
Ситуация такая. У меня есть приложение на node.js , запускаю его при помощи pm2. Недавно пришлось переезжать на nginx дабы получить SSL сертификат через certbot.
Помучался немного с настройками nginx , удалось открыть сайт по адресу из настроек, но все роуты, все стили, слетело всё, остался голый одностраничный html :)

Понимаю, что дело в путях, но пути все написаны и отлично отрабатывали до переезда. Подскажите в чём может быть проблема.
Спасибо за понимание)

Answer (score 0):

Сработал костыль!

1. Указал путь к файлу css location / {root /var/www/site/public;}
   это вернуло стили.
2. ПС роутами справился вот так, как на скрине)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядит как костылище, но всё заработало!